# Есть ли в vb10 и vb.net свойства ListCount у ListBox?

Tags: vba, vb.net, visual-basic

В VB 6.0 оказывается есть ListCount в свойствах ListBox. И теперь мне нужно такое же св-во в VB10. Есть ли такое или аналог ему?

Comment: Уже проверил нет про это инф-ии. Возможно такого св-ва нет, но мне не верится что в 6-ке в качестве св-ва счётчик был, а в 10-ой версии его вырезали, мол сами пишите код. Наверняка есть и называется как-то по другому, вот решил спросить тех кто пользуется (долго использует) этим языком

Comment: Неужели в vb10 для счётчик надо отдельно код писать?!

Comment: А можно для непросвещенных, что это свойство должно делать, возвращать количество элементов в списке?

Comment: Да, служит своего рода счётчиком списка

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.count(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: >>Уже проверил нет про это инф-ии<< Мы смотрим разные документации?

Comment: ListBox.ObjectCollection.Count - свойство. По вашей ссылке нашёл только это касающееся счётчика. И здесь требуется прописать класс/ф-ию в декларации чтобы можно было 
вызвать в теле программы.
И возвращаясь к теме вопроса получается снова прописываешь код, но в этот раз уже по сложнее, нужно в декларации его прописать, чтобы появилась возможность вызвать/обратиться к нему!!!
Я имел ввиду просто св-во типа .Item.Add или .Item.Clear() или хотя бы внутреннюю ф-ию VB10

Comment: Столько слов, и ноль смысла... Что вы только что сказали? Вы знаете как коллекциями пользоваться?

Comment: Чем не угодил ListBox.Items.Count?

Comment: >>св-во типа .Item.Add или .Item.Clear()<< ??? Какие свойства? Короче, гуглите книгу по VB.NET, читайте её (не листайте оглавление и первые страницы введения, а именно читайте, и читайте всю книгу), изучайте msdn, на нём есть около 90% информации по языку, смотрите сорсы от MS, все библиотеки довольно подробно расписаны и выложены в открытом доступе. Сейчас, вы говорите несуразицу.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой подход:

```
Dim i as integer = 0
For Each item In myListBox.Items
    'ваш код

Next item
```

или же : myListBox.Items.Count